# How can I make siunitx's \num bold?

Tags: siunitx, bold

What I want:

[image]

### Minimal Example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[binary-units,group-separator={,}]{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=fraction,
         binary-units=true,
         group-separator = {\,},
         range-phrase=-}
\DeclareSIUnit\pixel{px}
\DeclareSIUnit\float{float}
\DeclareSIUnit\floats{floats}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cllrrl}
    \toprule
    \# & Type                     & \parbox[t]{3cm}{Filters @\par Patch size / stride} & Parameters & FLOPs & Output size  \\\midrule
       & Input                    &                                           &          0  &            0 & \hphantom{0}1 @ $32\times 32$    \\
    1  & Convolution              & \hphantom{0}6 @ $5 \times 5 \times 1$ / 1 &        156  & \num{307800} & \hphantom{0}\bf{6}\,@\,$\mathbf{28\times 28}$    \\
    2  & Scaled average pooling   & \hphantom{00 @} $2 \times 2 \hphantom{\times 00}$ / 2 &          2  &    \num{336} & \hphantom{0}6 @ $14\times 14$    \\
    3  & Convolution              & 16 @ $5 \times 5 \times 6$ / 1            &  \num{2416} & \bf{\num{942400}} & 16 @ $10\times 10$ \\
    4  & Scaled average pooling   & \hphantom{00 @} $2 \times 2 \hphantom{\times 00}$ / 2 &          2  &   \num{1600} & 16 @ \hphantom{0}$5\times \hphantom{0}5$   \\
    5  & Fully Connected          & 120 neurons                      & \ensuremath{\boldmath\num{48120}} & \num{240000} & 120 \\
    6  & Fully Connected          & \hphantom{0}84 neurons           & \num{10164} &  \num{20580} & \hphantom{0}84 \\
    7  & Fully Connected (output) & \hphantom{0}10 neurons           &        850  &   \num{1730} & \hphantom{0}10 \\\midrule
    $\sum$ &                      &                                  & \num{61710} &\num{15144446}& \num{9118}\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

### What I tried

I've tried putting `\num` into math mode and `\mathbf` / `\boldmath`, `\bf`, `\bfseries`. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not perfectly aligned since bold fonts are wider than non bold. Bold fonts are achieved by `siunitx` package option `detect-weight` and use of `S` column type in third and fourth column:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\usepackage[binary-units,group-separator={,}]{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=fraction,
         binary-units=true,
         group-separator = {\,},
         range-phrase=-}
\DeclareSIUnit\pixel{px}
\DeclareSIUnit\float{float}
\DeclareSIUnit\floats{floats}

\usepackage{etoolbox}% <-- for bold fonts
\newcommand{\ubold}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}% <-- for bold fonts
\robustify\ubold% <-- for bold fonts

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cll 
                    S[detect-weight,group-minimum-digits = 4,table-format=5.0]% <-- changed
                    S[detect-weight,group-minimum-digits = 4,table-format=8.0]% <-- changed
                    l}
    \toprule
\# &    Type                     
        &   \thead[tl]{Filters @\\ Patch size / stride} 
            &   {Parameters}    &   {FLOPs}   & Output size  \\\midrule
   &    Input                    
        &   &           0       &       0   & \hphantom{0}1 @ $32\times 32$    \\
1  &    Convolution              
        &   \hphantom{0}6 @ $5 \times 5 \times 1$ / 1 
            &       156         &   307 800 & \hphantom{0}\textbf{6}\,@\,$\mathbf{28\times 28}$    \\
2  &    Scaled average pooling   
        & \hphantom{00 @} $2 \times 2 \hphantom{\times 00}$ / 2 
            &        2          &       336 & \hphantom{0}6 @ $14\times 14$    \\
3  &    Convolution              
        &   16 @ $5 \times 5 \times 6$ / 1            
            &   2 416           & \ubold 942 400% <-- boldface
                                    & 16 @ $10\times 10$ \\
4  &    Scaled average pooling   
        &   \hphantom{00 @} $2 \times 2 \hphantom{\times 00}$ / 2 
            &        2          &     1 600 & 16 @ \hphantom{0}$5\times \hphantom{0}5$   \\
5  &    Fully Connected          
        &   120 neurons                      
            & \ubold 48 120% <-- boldface
                & 240 000   & 120 \\
6  &    Fully Connected          
        &   \hphantom{0}84 neurons           
                &       10 164  &   20 580  & \hphantom{0}84 \\
7  & Fully Connected (output) 
        &   \hphantom{0}10 neurons           
            &               850 &   1 730   & \hphantom{0}10 \\ \midrule
$\sum$  &   &   &        61 710 & 15 144 446& \num{9118}\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: use of \bf is depreciated for + 20 years.

**Edit:**

Meanwhile (after many years and comments below) many of us learned how to managed boldface digits in `S` column tables. In original answer was not added option `mode=text` to `\sisetup` and definition of `ubold` can also be improved:

```
% preamble as before
\usepackage{etoolbox}% <-- for robustify bold fonts in S columns
\newrobustcmd\ubold{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}\bfseries}% <-- changed

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\sisetup{detect-weight,
         group-minimum-digits = 4,
         mode=text    % <--- added
         }
    \begin{tabular}{cll
                    S[table-format=5.0]% <-- changed
                    S[table-format=8.0]% <-- changed
                    l}
% table body
```

Considering above in MWE gives desired result:

[image]

Comment: The alignment problem can be solved, see egreg answer!

Comment: @CarLaTeX, I'm slightly confused: my definition of boldface fonts is not (so) different from egres's, but gives different result.  I must deeply investigate this.

Comment: There's always to learn from egreg :):):)

Answer (score 14):

You can locally redefine `\bfseries` to use `\fontseries{b}`, rather than `\fontseries{bx}` as usual.

You can also avoid all those phantoms by using more columns.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell,etoolbox}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\usepackage[binary-units,group-separator={,}]{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=fraction,
         binary-units=true,
         group-separator = {\,},
         range-phrase=-}
\DeclareSIUnit\pixel{px}
\DeclareSIUnit\float{float}
\DeclareSIUnit\floats{floats}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\renewrobustcmd{\bfseries}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
\sisetup{detect-weight,mode=text,group-minimum-digits = 4}

\centering

\small
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-1.5pt}% decide at the end
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  c
  l
  S[table-format=3.0]@{\,}c@{\,}l@{\,}c@{\,}l
  S[table-format=5.0]
  S[table-format=8.0]
  S[table-format=4.0]@{\,}c@{\,}S[table-format=2.0]@{}>{${}}c<{{}$}@{}S[table-format=2.0]
  @{}
    }
\toprule
\# & Type
   & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}Filters @\\ Patch size / stride\end{tabular}}
   & {Parameters}
   & {FLOPs}
   & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Output size}
\\
\midrule
  &    Input                    
       &&&&&   &           0       &       0   & 1 & @ & 32 & \times & 32    \\
1 &    Convolution
       & 6 & @ & $5 \times 5 \times 1$ & / & 1 
       & 156 & 307 800 & \bfseries 6 & @ & \bfseries 28 & \times & \bfseries 28 \\
2 &    Scaled average pooling   
       &&& $2 \times 2$ & / & 2
       & 2 & 336 & 6 & @ & 14 & \times & 14 \\
3 &    Convolution
       & 16 & @ & $5 \times 5 \times 6$ & / & 1
       & 2 416 & \bfseries 942 400 & 16 & @ & 10 & \times & 10 \\
4 &    Scaled average pooling
       &&& $2 \times 2$ & / & 2
       & 2 & 1 600 & 16 & @ & 5 & \times & 5 \\
5 &    Fully Connected
        & 120 & \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\ neurons}
        & \bfseries 48 120 & 240 000   & 120 \\
6 &    Fully Connected
        & 84 & \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\ neurons}
        & 10 164 & 20 580  & 84 \\
7 & Fully Connected (output)
        & 10 & \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\ neurons}
        & 850 & 1 730 & 10 \\ \midrule
$\sum$  &&&&&&& 61 710 & 15 144 446 & 9118\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, be so kind and explain me, where is the main difference between your and mine definition of boldface fonts used in table?

Comment: @Zarko `mode=text`

Comment: thank you very much. my first test was with `iwona` condensed fonts, where differences between width boldface an ordinar characters was not so visible. so I didn't pay attention to `mode=text` in `siunitx` preset ... well, I learned something new!

Answer (score 0):

I post an additional answer since I can't comment yet.

To anyone coming here with a newer version of latex, see [this question and answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530451/siunitx-is-feature-of-the-mode-text-changed).

According to the answer, the behaviour of \bfseries changed. @egreg's solution with mode=text still works when defining a new robust command like

```
\newrobustcmd\B{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}\bfseries}
```

and using that command (`\B`) within the table instead of `\bfseries`.