# siunitx, bold numbers in cell with cell content start with \$

Tags: siunitx, bold

Based on egreg answer on question [how-can-i-make-siunitxs-num-bold](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351981) i try to make the following table:

```
\documentclass[12pt,
               border=2mm,
               preview]{standalone}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
\newrobustcmd{\B}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{table}
\sisetup{detect-weight, mode=text, table-format=2.2}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{ l >{\$}S[table-align-text-pre=false,
                          table-space-text-pre =\$ ]
                        S[table-space-text-post=\,]<{\%}
               }
\toprule
text a  &   \B  17.89   &   \B  10.29   \\
text b  &        0.29   &        7.89   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Is possible to convince `siunitx` that also the second cell in the first row to be write in bold?

Comment: Interesting feature. Anyway, repeated marker should be avoided and put in the column header.

Comment: @Bernard As I understood he wants the "17.89" to be bold.

Comment: @Bernard The second cell in the *first* row has `\B`, but the entry is not emboldened.

Comment: The `>{\$}` somehow prevents the cell from being bold.

Comment: @Bernard, no, the second cells in the first row, which has `B`, but not appear in bold (as stated egreg in his comment).

Comment: @samcarter Yes, *anything* in `>{...}` does the same.

Comment: @egreg, in normal circumstances the `$˙should be in column headers, but I saw some question here with such demands, so I start to thinking how to solve this with `siunitx`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens as `siunitx` is trying to maintain alignment. The material before the number is typeset in a box, which means that any colour or font change commands will be lost. You don't see that with just a font switch as it's zero-width: that's detected and inserted directly (not boxed). You can get around this by making the inserted material have zero width:

```
\documentclass[12pt,
               border=2mm,
               preview]{standalone}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
\newrobustcmd{\B}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{table}
\sisetup{detect-weight, mode=text, table-format = 2.2}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{ l >{{\makebox[0pt][l]{\$}}}S[table-align-text-pre=true,
                          table-space-text-pre =\$ ]
                        S[table-space-text-post={\,\%}]<{\,\%}
               }
\toprule
text a  &   \B 17.89   &   \B  10.29\cr
text b  &        0.29   &        7.89\cr
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

A bug shows up in `siunitx` when you do this as the `$` tokens are duplicated. A fix will be on CTAN later today. It can be fixed for the moment using

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\patchcmd \__siunitx_table_print_S_reserved_ends:
  { \l__siunitx_table_collect_pre_tl \bool_set_false:N }
  { \box_clear:N \l__siunitx_table_pre_box
    \l__siunitx_table_collect_pre_tl \bool_set_false:N
  }
  { }
  { }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I try to replace `>{{\makebox[0pt][l]{\$}}}` with shorter `>{\rlap{\$}}` and this also works. Both makes numbers bold, but `table-align-text-pre=false,` doesn't work anymore :-(

Comment: @Zarko `\rlap` isn't a LaTeX command

Comment: @Zarko I'll see if I can sort the alignment issue: it's tricky with the current code set up