# Decimal alignment in a table with math mode

Tags: tables, booktabs, overleaf, dcolumn

After reading some answers on the site, I'm trying to use dcolumn pacakge in order to add horizontal alignment to my tables.
Unfortunately without success so far.
I'm writing as a part of a group so I shouldn't added packages that may affect others, that's why I'm trying to figure it w/o adding the `siunitx` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn} 
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1} }


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lc*{4}{d{1.5}}@{}}
        \toprule
        {} & {} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Group A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Group B} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){3-4}  \cmidrule(l){5-6}
        Types & Character & Results A & Results B     & Results A & Results B     \\
        \midrule
        \multirow{3}{*}{Main}
        {}    & The Good & .111      & .789_{b}^{b}  & .520      & .555_{b}^{a}  \\
        {}    & The Bad  & .111      & .636_{b}^{al} & .520      & .730_{b}^{al} \\
        {}    & The Ugly & .111      & .525_{b}      & .520      & .696_{b}      \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

The result is:

[image: result table]

Please help me solve this puzzle, also I need to add bold to some values in the table, and since switching to dcolumn I've removed the `$n$` I've had and therefore \mathbf seems not to work any more. What would be the solution in that case?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I know you stated your reasons for not using `siunitx` but, imho, you should take a careful look at it, for it is very well crafted and resourceful. Besides, you do load `dcolumn` don't you?

Comment: @gusbrs Yes, I have added the dcolumn loading. But from my (very narrow) understanding in LaTeX it seems to me as a more basic package, that should be in the basic libraries without any further installation. Personally I work in Overleaf, but some other group members use offline editors (which I know little about) so I'm afraid that adding a more advanced package may cause some issues with them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably looking for `\multicolumn`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1} }


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}lc*{4}{d{1.5}}@{}}
    \toprule
    {} & {} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Group A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Group B} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-4}  \cmidrule(l){5-6}
    Types & Character & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Results A} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Results B} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Results A} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Results B}  \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{3}{*}{Main}
    {}    & The Good & .111      & .789_{b}^{b}  & .520      & .555_{b}^{a}  \\
    {}    & The Bad  & .111      & .636_{b}^{al} & .520      & .730_{b}^{al} \\
    {}    & The Ugly & .111      & .525_{b}      & .520      & .696_{b}      \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, as mentioned in the comments, I think you should reconsider the case against `siunitx`. More important than being a "basic package" is the fact that it is very well crafted and zealously maintained, besides being widely used. (This is not a judgement on `dcolumn` of which I'm not an user). You should, of course, decide that along with your work group.

The same table done with `siunitx` would be something like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \sisetup{table-format = 0.3}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}
    lc
    S
    S[table-space-text-post = {$_{b}^{al}$}] % make it the largest post-number element
    S
    S[table-space-text-post = {$_{b}^{al}$}]
    @{}}
    \toprule
          &           & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Group A}     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Group B}    \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-4}  \cmidrule(l){5-6}
    Types & Character & {Results A} & {Results B}       & {Results A} & {Results B}      \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{3}{*}{Main}
          & The Good  & .111        & .789{$_{b}^{b}$}  & .520        & .555{$_{b}^{a}$}  \\
          & The Bad   & .111        & .636{$_{b}^{al}$} & .520        & .730{$_{b}^{al}$} \\
          & The Ugly  & .111        & .525{$_{b}$}      & .520        & .696{$_{b}$}      \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

It does automatically take care of the leading zero, emphasized by @Denis in the comments.

[image]

Comment: Thanks id did solved my problem, can you perhaps add a solution using `siunitx` ?

Comment: btw, sorry that I can't upvote yet..

Comment: @Oleg Also note that the SI manual says that you should always write `.11` as `0.11`.

Comment: @Denis will it still appear in the table as .11 ?
All my tables are generated by code so I don't have a problem changing the format - but I do need it to be in that form eventually

Comment: @Oleg As I understand the SI brochure, we should always write `0.11`, including in tables.

Comment: @Oleg To be precise, this is page 44 of the SI brochure (French Edition, which is the official edition).

Comment: @Oleg See edit for an `siunitx` equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

You can (should, in my opinion) use `siunitx`; here I show also how to have real note markers upright that leave the exact space for them.

If you want to set some of the entries bold, there is a trick adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/352028/4427

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\NewDocumentCommand{\bs}{}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\tss}{mm}{%
  {\m@th\ensuremath{%
    ^{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@\selectfont #1}}%
    _{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@\selectfont #2}}%
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\sisetup{detect-weight,mode=text}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\bfseries}{}{\bs}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  c
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=1.3,table-space-text-post=\tss{al}{b}]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=1.3,table-space-text-post=\tss{al}{b}]
  @{}
}
\toprule
 & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Group A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Group B} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4}  \cmidrule(l){5-6}
Types & Character & {Results A} & {Results B} & {Results A} & {Results B} \\
\midrule
Main & The Good & \bs .111 & .789\tss{b}{b}  & .520 & .555\tss{a}{b}  \\
     & The Bad  &     .111 & .636\tss{al}{b} & .520 & .730\tss{al}{b} \\
     & The Ugly &     .111 & .525\tss{}{b}   & .520 & .696\tss{}{b}   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:my_label}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I wouldn't use `\multirow`: blank space below “Main” means repetition. Shifting it down makes quite unclear whether “Main” refers to all rows or just the middle one.

[image]

Comment: Although it doesn't directly answer my question, but it's also a great answer. Thank you.
Just one question, I've noticed that the values in the table don't appear to be in math mode, i.e not italic as it appears in the example above - can it be changed?

Comment: @Oleg The sub/superscript seem better go in upright type. Of course, I don't know what they refer to, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: In the original file they stand for statistical significance, is this the line that controls it ? 
`S[table-format=1.3,table-space-text-post=\tss{al}{b}]`

Comment: @Oleg No, it's the definition of `\tss` (short for `\textsupersubscript`). If you want them to be in italics, change both occurrences of `\selectfont` into `\itshape`.